# Odd Composite Proof

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, mersenne-numbers

When $n$ is an odd natural composite number, $\frac{2^n + 1}{3}$ is always composite. Prove this conjecture.

I'm not 100% sure but I let $n$ = $2c+1$ = $ab$, where $c$ is a natural number including $0$, and $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers, where $1<a$ and $b<n$.

$\frac{2^{ab} + 1}{3}$ = $\frac{(2^b + 1)(1-2^b+2^{2b}+.....+2^{b(a-1)})}{3}$. Now let $x$ = $2^b + 1$, $y$ = $(1-2^b+2^{2b}+.....+2^{b(a-1)})$.

I know that I can prove that the numerator is composite as $1<b<n$, so $1$<$x$< $2^n + 1$, which implies that $1$<$y$<$2^n + 1$, which means that the numerator is composite.

I am stuck with the divided by $3$ part. I guess I should use the fact that $n$ is odd but I am not sure how valid my proof is. Is it do with the fact that the numerator is somehow a multiple of 3 when $n$ is odd, which I guess I could prove using induction ?

How bad is my proof ? :( Thanks guys!

Comment: This is hard to read.  Note that if you want to get more than one character into an exponent you need to surround them with curly brackets.  This 2^{2b} renders as $2^{2b}$.

Comment: It's not just hard to read, as @lulu points out; it's actually ambiguous: We don't know which parts are in the exponent as it stands, and which parts are not.

Comment: @lulu fixed now

Comment: @BrianTung Fixed now

Comment: Yes, in general $2^a+1$ divides $2^{ab}+1$ and you should know that $2^a+1$ is not prime unless $a$ is a power of $2$ (and usually not even then).  Just play with that.

Comment: @lulu Do you mean 2 to the power of b and not a ? I’m not 100% sure on what you said. Could you please tell me where in my proof I have gone wrong / what I have left to prove ? Thank you :)

Comment: Boh $2^a+1$ and $2^b+1$ divide $2^{ab}+1$  Pick either of them.  Since $a,b≥3$ which ever you pick is at least $9$ and both are divisible by $3$.   That's all you need.

Comment: Ohhh so for the numerator which I factorised I’m proving it’s a multiple of 3 as when divided by 3 it will always be an integer, and I already proved that it’s composite ?! @lulu

Comment: Was the n = 2c + 1 part of my proof necessary or just the n = ab @lulu I don’t understand where you get a, b >= 3 from. Also, you said both are divisible by 3, do I need to prove that, or is there something intuitive I am missing ?

Comment: My bad, a, b >= 3 because n is an odd natural composite natural number, so 9,15,21….

Comment: @lulu or anyone else, just seeking final clarifications above please

Comment: Yes, if an odd number $m$ is composite, then we can write $m=ab$ where $a,b$ are both odd and $≥3$.

Comment: You have shown $\frac{2^b+1}{3}\mid \frac{2^{ab}+1}{3}$ , you only need to show $1<\frac{2^b+1}{3}<\frac{2^{ab}+1}{3}$ to finish the proof (which follows immediately from $a,b>1$)